# Loading external data in d3 version 5 using promise

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise, xmlhttprequest

I was going through the changes in d3 version 5 here : https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

One of the most important change in this version has been for loading of external csv/tsv/json data. D3 now loads the data as a promise rather than XHR. Consequently, data load process would change from many aspects (callback, error handling etc.).

Quoting from the above link:

> D3 now uses Promises instead of asynchronous callbacks to load data. Promises simplify the structure of asynchronous code, especially in modern browsers that support async and await.
>
> For example, to load a CSV file in v4, you might say:

```
d3.csv("file.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(data);
});
In v5, using promises:

d3.csv("file.csv").then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

> Note that you don’t need to rethrow the error—the promise will reject
>   automatically, and you can promise.catch if desired.

What do the above statements mean? I am not very familiar with how html requests (XHR, promises) work so I wanted to know, what were the reasons behind this change and as a developer how does this improve the data loading functionality.

Thanks for the help in advance.